# SQL help - Trying to tag values which complement the same number with opposite sign

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

I am trying to flag the numbers in a column which has both positive and negative numbers and adds to zero if summed up. I would like to do this by partitioning one table into multiple chunks based on Account column in the table.
I have posted a picture to further explain how my result (Flag column) is expected.
I am novice to this, and would appreciate all the help I can get.
Thanks All.

[SQL help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk1iE.png)

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results as per [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Hi @Shahul please provide sample data.

Comment: Hi Stu .. Sure i will do it from next time.
Hi @RahulBiswas .. i have given it in images.. *SQL Help*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather tricky because of duplicates.  The idea is to enumerate the values for each account and then use a window function for the flag:

```
select t.*,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by account, abs(amount), seqnum) = 2
             then 1 else 0 
        end) as flag
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by account, amount order by amount) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

This may look a little arcane ("where does that "2" come from?).  The subquery is enumerating each amount for each account by adding a sequence number.

The outer query is then counting the number of values for the absolute value of the amount by sequence number.  The number can only be 1 or 2.  If it is 2, then there must be a positive and negative value (because `row_number()` prevents two values of the same sign from having the same sequence number).

Answer (score -1):

Use `lead(),lag()` and `row_number()` function .  If the current record is even, compare it with the previous record, and if it is odd, compare it with the next record.

```
SELECT Account,
       Amount,
       CASE 
        WHEN seq % 2 = 0 THEN (CASE WHEN amount = (-1) * prev THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        WHEN seq % 2 > 0 THEN (CASE WHEN amount = (-1) * next THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END flag
FROM
(SELECT *,
      row_number() over(partition BY Account ORDER BY Account) AS seq,
      lag(Amount) over(partition BY Account ORDER BY Account) AS prev,
      lead(Amount) over(partition BY Account ORDER BY Account) AS next
FROM tb) t
```

demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=aa117392b3cad822d18e2b7840f44c12)

Comment: Thanks for the time @Meysam Asadi.. 
I tried this, and it had one flaw.. 
Account, Amount, flag,
5703, 67, 0,
5703, -5.6, 0,
5703, -67, 0,
5703, -67, 0,
5703, -5.6, 1,
5703, 5.6, 1,
In this case, 67 and -67 did not get flagged, may be because there was two 67's in the data.
But appreciate the help :)

Sorry i did not know how to paste table here. :(

Comment: Enter the data you want in dbfiddle and comment on the link to check.